# How to type function output from generic parameter?

Tags: typescript

I have a function that accepts an array of string as a parameter, and parses the url to return an object with the correct value for each requested field. For exemple:

```js
const getUrlParamsAsObject = (params: string[) => {
  const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.hash.split("?")[1]);
  return reduce(
    params,
    (acc, param) => {
      if (urlParams.has(param)) {
        acc[param] = urlParams.get(param);
      }
      return acc;
    },
    {}
  );
};

// getUrlParamsAsObject(["product"])
// output: {product: "hammer"}
```

How to properly type the output of this function? I've written:

```js
const getUrlParamsAsObject = <T extends string[]>(params: T): : Record<keyof T, string> => {
```

`: Record<keyof T, string>` is supposed to be an object whose keys are the fields in T[], and whose values are string.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could paste the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/N7OKDN) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.  (For example, you have at least one typo, and an undeclared `reduce` function).

Comment: And... you're getting search parameters from the *`hash`* part of the url? That's strange, usually it would be `search`.  Could you maybe minimize the example to some toy thing that doesn't invite further questions unrelated to your stated goal of typing function outputs from generic parameters?  You can write `<K extends string>(params: K[]): Record<K, string>`, but the actual function implementation shown is unlikely to produce things with those properties, even if you do fix up `reduce` and the typo.  I'd suggest [this version](https://tsplay.dev/Nr5Glw) instead. Does that work?